# How to disable Enter Key for a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, binding

I have a button that has a command binded to it and also a key binding for <kbd>F1</kbd> key. When the focus is on that button, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key also triggers the command, which I do not want. I want the button to be triggered only for <kbd>F1</kbd> and mouse click. How to disable this <kbd>Enter</kbd> key?

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Content="Run (F1)" Margin="10,4" Width="100" FontSize="16" Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BlackButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,ElementName=TestButton}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=TestButton}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

My key binding is as follows:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding Path=TestViewModel.TestRunCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

When I remove the focus trigger, then the <kbd>F1</kbd> key is also not working. So, I had this `Setter` property for <kbd>F1</kbd> key to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out a simple way to block Enter Key by adding `KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="False"`.

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Content="Run (F1)" Margin="10,4" Width="100" FontSize="16" Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}" KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn="False">
```

This worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach an event handler for the `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Content="Run (F1)" Margin="10,4" Width="100" FontSize="16" Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}" PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown">
```

In the event handler, check for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and handle the event.

```
private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == key.Return);
}
```

---

A slightly more creative variant would be to create an `ICommand` that does not do anything. It would be bound as `KeyBinding` to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, thus blocking the original command. I created a markup extension just for the ease of use.

```
public class IgnoreCommandExtension : MarkupExtension
{
   private static readonly IgnoreCommand IgnoreCommandInstance = new IgnoreCommand();

   private class IgnoreCommand : ICommand
   {
      public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
      {
         return true;
      }

      public void Execute(object parameter)
      {
      }

      public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
   }

   public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      return IgnoreCommandInstance;
   }
}
```

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Content="Run (F1)" Margin="10,4" Width="100" FontSize="16" Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}">
    <Button.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{local:IgnoreCommand}"/>
       <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{local:IgnoreCommand}"/>
    </Button.InputBindings>
    <!-- ...other code. -->
</Button>
```

Comment: Added another variant that uses key bindings instead of an event handler.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}"` from `<Button ...>` and the button won't do anything when being pressed.

Here's a minimal and complete example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DC/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding Path=F1Command}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="TestButton" Content="Run (F1)" Margin="10,4" Width="100" FontSize="16" 
Command="{Binding TestRunCommand}">
<!-- ^- remove this if you want it to do nothing -->
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button" >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,ElementName=TestButton}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=TestButton}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class DC
{
    public ICommand TestRunCommand
    {
        get { return new CommandHandler(() => MessageBox.Show("Enter / Space / Click"), () => true); }
    }

    public ICommand F1Command
    {
        get { return new CommandHandler(() => MessageBox.Show("F1"), () => true); }
    }
}

public class CommandHandler : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    public CommandHandler(Action action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute.Invoke();
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _action();
}
```

Comment: By removing that command, then the mouse click functionality will not work.. I want the button command to be triggered on 2 cases - mouse click and F1 key.. Not with Enter.

Comment: Okay... next time you might want to keep the original requirements and not change the question, please. As you do not like your Product Owner to change the requirements during the sprint, we don't like changing questions here.